# c# generic class and method not behaving as expected

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following code

```
public class BaseDataRepository<T> : IDataRepository, IDisposable where T:class
    {
        public IQueryable<T> GetItems<T>() where T : class
        {
            return _context.Set<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

used the following way

```
using (var repository = new BaseDataRepository<DbInterestGroupCategory>())
{
    Assert.IsTrue(repository.GetItems().Count() == 3);
}
```

But I get the following message

> The type arguments for method '...' cannot be inferred from the usage.
>   Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I would have thought the method would automatically infer it's T parameter from the classes generic type. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should see a compile warning about the method type parameter having the same name as the outer class type parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are re-declaring the generic argument on the method level (it's already defined on a class level), so you now have an (independently) generic method in a generic class. I.e. you could write code like this:

```
//DbInterestGroupCategory is the class-level T
var repository = new BaseDataRepository<DbInterestGroupCategory>(); 
//string is the method level T
repository.GetItems<string>();
```

What you have done is essentially analogous to

```
public class MyClass 
{
  public string Name {get; set;}

  public string Method()
  {
    string Name; // hides the class level property
    ....
  }
}
```

What you need is a method that is not generic relative to the class, since it does not introduces any generic parameters, it merely uses those already defined in the class, so the correct syntax is:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetItems()
{
  return _context.Set<T>();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Remove the `<T>` from the method you already declared it in class

```
public class BaseDataRepository<T> : IDataRepository, IDisposable where T:class
{
    public IQueryable<T> GetItems()
    {
        return _context.Set<T>();
    }
}
```

`T` in methods are inferred by arguments like this:

```
public void DoSomething<T>(T argument) // infer T from argument
{
}

// so you can call

DoSomething(new object()); // T is object
```

Comment: Beaten by 7 seconds. Well played!

Answer (score 1):

By declaring a method `GetItems<T>`, you are creating a new "T" template variable which is not the same. Remove it.